# How to display httpClient error to user in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

My **service** looks like this:

```
sortTraceGroups(): Observable<TraceGroup[]> {
    const url = environment.servicesBaseUrl + 'api/trace/sort?sort=' + this.sortChosen;
    return this.httpClient.post<TraceGroup[]>(url, this.traceGroups)
                          .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<never> {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `couldn't get response from server. ElasticSearch is probably down.`);
    }
    return throwError(`Error: couldn't get response from server.`);
  }
}
```

This is a **component** which subscribe to http call

```
onSortChoose(sortChosen: SortChosen): void {
    this.traceService.setSortChosen(sortChosen);
    this.traceService.sortTraceGroups()
      .subscribe(
        traceGroupsSorted => {
          this.traceGroups = traceGroupsSorted;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.error = error;
        }
      );
}
```

Now I tried to show error message in my **html** like this

```
<div *ngIf="error" class="offset-md-3 col-md-6 alert alert-danger row justify-content-center" role="alert">
  {{ error }}
</div>
```

It works fine when error occurs for the first time. 
However when I do another call and it finish successfully I don't want to show the error message anymore. The only solution I come up is to update error message every time I do http call which seems to me incorrect.

```
onSortChoose(sortChosen: SortChosen): void {
    this.traceService.setSortChosen(sortChosen);
    this.traceService.sortTraceGroups()
      .subscribe(
        traceGroupsSorted => {
          this.traceGroups = traceGroupsSorted;
          this.error = ''; // do I need this line in every http call just to reset error message ?
        },
        (error) => {
          this.error = error;
        }
      );
}
```

Is there an elegant way to display error in html only when http call fails and don't show when it ends successfully without changing error attribute every time ?
In this example it looks 'okayish' but sometime I need to share error between two components through service and it doesn't seems OK to call setter on service just to changed error message


Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an elegant way to display error in html only when `http` call
>   fails and don't show when it ends successfully without changing the error
>   attribute every time?

Nope, you have to unset the property.

But you can use `complete` handler for clearing the property instead of the `next` handler.
There are three functions available to send data to the subscribers of the observable:

1. `next`: send any value such as Numbers, Arrays or objects to its
   subscribers.
2. `error`: sends a Javascript error or exception
3. `complete`: does not send any value

> ```
> onSortChoose(sortChosen: SortChosen): void {
>   this.traceService.setSortChosen(sortChosen);
>   this.traceService.sortTraceGroups()
>     .subscribe(
>       traceGroupsSorted => {
>         this.traceGroups = traceGroupsSorted;
>       },
>       (error) => {
>         this.error = error;
>       },
>       () => this.error = ''; // do I need this line in every http call just to reset error message ?
>     );
> }
> ```

[`Defining observers`](https://angular.io/guide/observables#defining-observers)

Comment: Thanks, complete handler seems cleaner for me. I also find out I can use error popup and reset error msg when user close popup. Which is a nice alternative... But for now I stick with your solution because I don't want popups in my application :)